# c# PostAsync An error occurred while sending the request when deploy IIS

Tags: c#, json, iis, postman, httpclient

I'am using the HttpClient PostAsync method to call API with requestUri and content, its work fine in my console development, but when deployed to iis and running page get error in InnerExceptions "HttpRequestException  An error occurred while sending the request".

so, I tried to test calling the api with postman on the server but it worked,
then what is missing in my coding, here's mycode

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult TrackAPIRequest(MdlForm form)
{
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("myurlAPI");

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = baseAddress;

    MdlForm RateMdl = RequestParam(form);
    string BodyParam = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RateMdl.trackRequest);

    var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Username + ":" + Password);
    string val = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + val);

    StringContent content = new StringContent(BodyParam, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content).Result;
    var dataResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return Json(dataResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: 1) Check the status code 2) Check the server error logs 3) Attempt a minimal reproduction (ie. *exact text content used with Postman* and not whatever MdlForm is)

Comment: hi thankyou for answer, i check statuscode = 200, and i use content same as in postman but still not work.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: hi, sorry i just found out that i got an error exception like this "Unable to connect to the remote server", what should i do?

Comment: “Unable to connect to the remote server Error”, this error occurs because the connection is lost with the server. When you make authenticated calls, the client opens the connection and then closes it as well. more information you can refer to this link: [https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-server-issue](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-server-issue).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var response = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress,content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```